Move element to right or left with keyboard
So I'm trying to make this block move left or right based on the keypress, but for some reason when i move right and then when i move left it doesn't reach the left screen frame boundary. It seems to me that when i move right the whole frame moves to the right so the steps it takes to reach the left frame boundary reduces.
I don't know what's going wrong here.


var element = document.getElementById("lupo");
var val = 0;
var cal = 0;

document.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
  move(event.key);
});

function move(key) {
  switch (key) {
    case "a":
      console.log("bleh");
      val += 50;
      console.log(val);
      element.style.right = `${val}px`;
      break;
    case "d":
      console.log("brrr");
      cal += 50;
      console.log(cal);
      element.style.left = `${cal}px`;
      break;

    default:
      break;
  }
}
body {
  background-color: red
}

#lupo {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0%;
  margin: auto;
}
<div id="lupo"></div>




The block is obviously moving left and right based on keypress. However, you're modifying left and right while also having width on the block – that's going to conflict.

Just move one position relative to the position of the blocks left side, you will need to calculate the width of the block in your movement as well and also reset the position of the block in the dom each time you reset your key press.

You want to move your element #lupo on keydown on the x axis, so use only an x variable. Also, don't forget to event.preventDefault() to override the browser's default behavior (page scroll).  Also, use only element.style.left:


var element = document.getElementById("lupo");

var x = 0; // Use only the `x` axis 

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Add this
  if (!event.repeat) move(event.key);
});

function move(key) {
  switch (key) {
    case "a":
      x -= 50;
      element.style.left = `${x}px`; // use only `left` CSS prop
      break;
    case "d":
      x += 50;
      element.style.left = `${x}px`; // use only `left` CSS prop
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}
body { overflow: hidden; }

#lupo {
  height: 100px;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: orange;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
}
<div id="lupo">Use A,D keys to move</div>




Here's an alternative way without the switch/case statement:


const elLupo = document.querySelector("#lupo");
let x = 0;

const move = (x) => elLupo.style.left = `${(x)}px`;

const keyActions = {
  a: () => move(x -= 50),
  d: () => move(x += 50),
};

addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (!event.repeat) keyActions[event.key]?.();
});
body { overflow: hidden; }

#lupo {
  height: 100px;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: orange;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
}
<div id="lupo">Use: A,D keys to move</div>



or by modifying the CSS Property (Variable) on the translate CSS rule and modify it using style.setProperty() from JS. With this solution you can also add CSS transitions/animations:


const elLupo = document.querySelector("#lupo");
let x = 0;

const move = (x) => {
  elLupo.style.setProperty("--x", x);
};

const keyActions = {
  a: () => move(--x),
  d: () => move(++x),
};

addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (!event.repeat) keyActions[event.key]?.();
});
body { overflow: hidden; }

#lupo {
  height: 100px;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: orange;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  
  transition: translate 0.3s;
  translate: calc(var(--x, 0) * 50px) calc(var(--y, 0) * 50px);
}
<div id="lupo">Use: A,D keys to move</div>



Notice in the above examples the if (!event.repeat), added to prevent moving the element on key long-press.

Just excellent @Roko C. Buljan  What kind of function is the move function? for me to learn about it. Thanks

Thank you! @Mehdi I've simplified a bit the code since your comment, to create a separate move function (which only job is to move the element), and a separate keyActions Object which holds the functioins which names correspond to the needed keyboard Event.key value a and d that call the move function passing a modified x value as argument. The =>  syntax is called: Arrow Function

Thank you very much for your code change now it is quite more clear for me  and also thanks for taking Time to explain. Again really excellent

@RokoC.Buljan you're the goat man, this really helps thanks a bunch.
